# React-native(android) fetch запрос post для получения token,ошибка 400 на сервере

Tags: react-native, token, http-status-code-400

я пытаюсь сделать вход через определенного пользователя,использую react-native,сервер загрузил на azure,через postman все работает гладко.Для начала вод код :

```
async submit(){
        const { skullaniciAdi, sifre, password_confirmation } = this.state;
        this.setState({ error : '', loading : true });
        var info={
            UserName: skullaniciAdi,
            Password: sifre,
            grant_type : 'password'
        }
        var formdata=new FormData();
        for(var k in info){
            formdata.append(k,info[k]);
        }
        var headers={
            'Content-Type': 'x-www-form-unlencoded/json'
        }
        var formheader=new FormData();
        console.warn(info);
        for(var l in headers){
            formheader.append(l,headers[l]);
        }
try{
    fetch('https://eyvaauthapi.azurewebsites.net/auth/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: formheader,
        body : formdata
      })
        .then((response) => {
            console.warn(formdata);
            console.warn(formheader);
        console.warn(response);
        // deviceStorage.saveKey("id_token", response.data.jwt);
        // this.props.newJWT(response.data.jwt);
        console.warn("bittim");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.warn(error);
        this.onLoginFail();
        });
    }catch(error){}
}
```

[image: код]

при отправке дает ошибку сервера 400 
Вот : 
[image: ошибка]

Помогите пожалуйста.Благодарю за ранее!

Comment: Он же говорит вам `unsupported_grant_type` видимо `grant_type : 'password'` не нравится вашему серверу. Смотрите на сервере

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно было конвертировать тело в querystring.stringify.С помощью axios написал,на fetch не знаю как будет.

```
axios.post(
        'https://eyvaпuthapi.azurewebsites.net/auth/token',  querystring.stringify(
        {
            UserName: 'KenanAv75',
            Password: 'oFwEfrvr',
            grant_type : 'password'
        })
    )
    .then((response) => {
        console.warn(response);
    deviceStorage.saveKey("id_token", response.data.jwt);
    this.props.newJWT(response.data.jwt);
    console.warn("bittim");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
    });
```